# usb drive EEPROM IC how is memory read-only blocked and unblocked?

Tags: usb-device, eeprom, hard-drive

I notice ofteen free give-away usb thumb drive come with a certain memory space locked and unwritable so that a 4 GB flash drive for instance has 1GB of advert which cannot be format.
Given that thumb drives are quite standardized, for instance they have a IC SK6211 to interface a EEPROM IC to the computer and a crystal oscillator, I wonder where they hardwire the information to lock a certain space of the drive.
Is it a pin pulled to ground or something? any example available online or some common design in EEPROM IC?

[image: usb drive]

Comment: Note that the storage technology here is FLASH, not EEPROM.  It is *possible* that the controller IC has a small internal EEPROM area for configuration, but my suspicion is that the designers of chips for cost-conscious products would have long ago found that redundant, compared to grabbing a page from the huge FLASH IC next door to use for configuration information.

Answer (score 1):

I initially misread your question, but it seems like the link might still be of some use to you. I think most USB-flash memory controllers (like the Alcor ones in the blog post [here](http://www.myblog.bloggybloggy.com/fixing-hacked-usb-memory-stick-08-04-2008/)) will have some application which can be used to program low level configuration on the controller. Specifically, I wonder if the "low level" format option will allow you to bypass the read-only sectors.

Actually, this [link](http://about-flashdisk.blogspot.com/2010/03/software-repairs-usb-flash-drive-with.html) seems to have software that supports Skymedi controllers. Also, that site does seem sketch as well, so be sure you scan any executables linked for viruses/malware etc...

Comment: Your answer doesn't appear to address the question. The OP wants to change a read-only region to allow read/write access. I don't think the link you posted addresses this issue at all.

Comment: I mis-read the question initially, but have edited the answer to reflect the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/3456666/how-format-write-protected-flash-drive/) looks quite promising, provided you're comfortable editing the registry and  running command-line executables.

Personally, I would return StorageDevicePolicies to the previous state, and I would always suggest that others back up their registry before fiddling with it.

Comment: It's not a registry matter because I tried formatting the device under GNU/Linux and the problem persists, it's definitely a hardware lock, nothing the OS or registry can do to circumvent it.